# Checking a List whether it contains a certain value

Tags: java, list

Stuck on my algorithm, all I am trying to do is print the position where my `playerAway` string ( first element of `playerAway` List ) matches in any of element from `playerNames` List. I also want the index position form my `playerNames`, so what I did

```
public static void evaluationOfTrade(List tradeAway, List playerNames) {

    for (int i = tradeAway.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        String playerAway = (String) tradeAway.get(0);
        String playerAwaySearch = (String) playerNames.get(i);

        if (playerAway.equals(playerNames)) {
            System.out.println("Player found:" + " " + playerAway + " Index is : " + playerNames.indexOf(playerAway));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help? I've been reading up on ArrayLists and can't to find my answer.

Comment: `playerAway.equals(playerNames)` ?? Why are you doing this ? `playerAway` is a `String`, and `playerNames` is a `List`. Does it make sense to check equality between these ?

Comment: Im trying to see if that first value in that array list "tradeAway" , is in PlayerNames

Comment: you just want to check for the first element of `tradeway` ??? ! ? you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments

> Im trying to see if that first value in that array list "tradeAway" ,
>   is in PlayerNames

Hence I can assume you only wanted to search the `playerNamed` list against the first element from `tradeAway`. If that is so it does not make any sense to iterate the whole `tradeAway` list. You can just do it simply in couple of lines

```
    /* You might want to specify the List type rather than having bare List */
     public static void evaluationOfTrade(List<String> tradeAway,
                                          List<String> playerNames) {

        String playerAway =  tradeAway.get(0);

        if (playerNames.contains(playerAway)) {
            System.out.println("Player found:" + " " + playerAway + " Index is : " + playerNames.indexOf(playerAway));
        }
     }
```

Here `contains()` methos is used from `Collection` interface that returns a boolean value telling whether the parameter object is being contained by the list.

But if you want to stick to a **for loop** following will do as well

```
public static void evaluationOfTrade(List<String> tradeAway,
                                     List<String> playerNames) {

     String playerAway = tradeAway.get(0);

     for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.size(); i++) {
          if (playerAway.equals(playerNames.get(i))) {
              System.out.println("Player found:" + " " + playerAway + " Index is : " + playerNames.indexOf(playerAway));
          }
     }
}
```

**NB:** this will print all matched Names including the case if the list has duplicate match

Comment: thanks for the help bro, but im just testing to see if a iteration does work. I will be expanding later, thats why im interested in the loop. can you please modify your answer a bit. I want to give you the points because of your excellent work

Comment: well. that is pretty straight forward also. updated the answer and I hope you would find it exactly what you are looking for

Comment: thanks man, got it. Enjoy your answer points! and most importantly take care

Comment: Welcome. its always a pleasure to help someone. Hope is, soon you will get the grip of java world. Happy learning.

Comment: one last thing, try to be precise and generic in asking a question in stackoverflow or in any community. That would help others to help you quicker. I updated your question. review that and change accordingly. You may not expect more downvote.